# jQuery Validate ignore custom validation rule if no value

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using the jQuery Validator plugin. Everything is working perfectly, I would like to make a final tweak. I'm just not having luck finding the correct combination.

I have a text input called "phone". If no value has been entered, I would like to ignore all rules - leaving the input alone. Currently, if I focus in, then focus out (without entering a value) the input is validated and my UI is updated with my valid markup. Which, is OK, but ideally, I'l like to leave the input alone. Only validate if there is a value.  I have to return true/false in my custom method otherwise it's always invalid.

Not sure what I can do. Thank you for your time!

**HTML**:

```
<input id="phone" name="phone" tabindex="7" placeholder="(###) ###-####" type="text" value="">
```

Here is my rule for this input:

**JavaScript**

```
....
'phone': {
            'required': {
                'depends': function(element) {
                    return $('#textOptIn').is(':checked');
                }
            },
            'hasValidPhoneNumber': true
        },
....
```

Here is my custom method:

**JavaScript**

```
$.validator.addMethod('hasValidPhoneNumber', function(value, element) {
    if (value === '' || value.replace(/ /g, '') === '(###)###-####')
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return isValidPhoneNumber(value); //
    }

}, messages.invalidPhoneNumber);



function isValidPhoneNumber(phoneNumber) {
    var pattern = /^[(]{0,1}[0-9]{3}[)]{0,1}[-\s\.]{0,1}[0-9]{3}[-\s\.]{0,1}[0-9]{4}$/;
    return pattern.test(phoneNumber);
}
```

Comment: Return `true` when the input is empty. The `required` method will prevent submitting an empty field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of checking if it's empty, use `this.optional(element)`.  It simply makes the field optional.  In other words, if you leave it blank, it's not going to be evaluated at all.

```
$.validator.addMethod('hasValidPhoneNumber', function(value, element) {
    if (this.optional(element) || value.replace(/ /g, '') === '(###)###-####') {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return isValidPhoneNumber(value); //
    }
}, messages.invalidPhoneNumber);
```

Comment: This helped uncover another method that was updating my UI based on valid or not. Using the optional here worked as I needed. Thank you very much!